# How do I write a SQLite query that pulls information from two tables while cross referencing a third?

Tags: database, sqlite, join

I have worked myself into a tricky situation and find myself unable to fight my way out of it with limited database experience. I've had three other developers at my office take a look at this and none of us have been able to conjure a method that does what I want to do without resorting to multiple queries. I'd really appreciate any help you may have to offer.

Here is a simplified look at my data structure:

```
[REPORTS]
store_number
item
actual_inventory

[STORES]
store_number
store_attribute1
store_attribute2
store_attribute3

[PLANS]
store_attribute1
store_attribute2
store_attribute3
item
target_inventory
```

Given a store_number, I need to be able to return all items, actual_inventory, and target_inventory.

Difficulty: There are items in [REPORTS] that are not in [PLANS] and vice versa.

This will return all [REPORTS] items for a store:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `REPORTS`
WHERE 
`store_number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>
```

This will return all [PLANS] items for a store:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PLANS`
WHERE 
`store_attribute1` =  (SELECT `store_attribute1` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
and `store_attribute2` = (SELECT `store_attribute2` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
and `store_attribute3` = (SELECT `store_attribute3` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
```

I just cannot figure out how to combine them! If I perform a UNION, I cannot seem to return the _inventory figures separately (in their own columns).

I have tried to simulate a FULL JOIN by performing two LEFT JOINS and performing a UNION. That returns results that I can't wrap my head around.

I have even tried to use VIEWS for each of those first two queries and SELECT FROM the VIEW to pull out data by STORE.

I am clearly missing something.

If I can return a list of unique items with associated target_inventory and actual_inventory numbers it will save me a ton of work in my application code.

Do I need to re-structure my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want all in the same list. Then I would do it with a `UNION ALL` and have a flag so you know which is the `actual_inventory` and what is the `target_inventory`.

```
SELECT 
  item
  actual_inventory as inventory,
  1 as isActual
FROM `REPORTS`
WHERE 
`store_number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  item
  target_inventory AS inventory,
  0 as isActual
FROM `PLANS`
WHERE 
`store_attribute1` =  (SELECT `store_attribute1` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
and `store_attribute2` = (SELECT `store_attribute2` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
and `store_attribute3` = (SELECT `store_attribute3` FROM `STORES` WHERE `number` = <<SOME NUMBER>>)
```

And that second question you have. It has to be a better way to write that. Like this maybe:

```
SELECT 
      item
      target_inventory AS inventory,
      0 as isActual
FROM `PLANS` as p
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        STORES as s
    WHERE
        s.store_attribute1=p.store_attribute1
        and s.store_attribute2=p.store_attribute2
        and s.store_attribute3=p.store_attribute3
        AND s.number = <<SOME NUMBER>>
)
```

if I understand your database diagram correct, your queries correct and you want to have `target_inventory` and `actual_inventory` in two column. Why can't you do like this?

```
SELECT
    STORES.store_number,
    PLANS.target_inventory,
    REPORTS.actual_inventory
FROM
    STORES
    LEFT JOIN REPORTS
        ON STORES.store_number=REPORTS.store_number
    LEFT JOIN PLANS
        ON STORES.store_attribute1=PLANS.store_attribute1
        AND STORES.store_attribute2=PLANS.store_attribute2
        AND STORES.store_attribute3=PLANS.store_attribute3
WHERE
    STORES.store_number=<<SOME NUMBER>>
```

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings :P

Comment: Your first example is spot on. I just have to adapt my application code. The last edit you threw up there does not quite work because it mismatches the items. Actually, it shows all combinations of items, I believe.

Comment: I'd love to upvote, but I lack the rep unfortunately. Thank you much for your help, though, sir. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would pull back all the relations you needed

```
SELECT 

    `REPORTS`.`item` as `Item Number`, 
    `REPORTS`.`actual_inventory` as `Inventory`, 
    `PLANS`.`target_inventory` as `Target Inventory`

FROM `REPORTS` as `r`, `STORES` as `s`, `PLANS` as `p`
WHERE `r`.`store_number` = `s`.`store_number`
AND `r`.`item` = `p`.`item`
AND `s`.`store_attribute1` = `p`.`store_attribute1`
AND `s`.`store_attribute2` = `p`.`store_attribute2`
AND `s`.`store_attribute3` = `p`.`store_attribute3`
```

If that doesn't work, maybe this?

```
SELECT
  `REPORTS`.`item` as `Item`, `REPORTS`.`actual_inventory`, `PLANS`.`target_inventory`
FROM
  `REPORTS`, `PLANS`
WHERE
  `REPORTS`.`store_number` IN (
                               SELECT `store_number` 
                               FROM `STORES` 
                               WHERE `store_attribute1` = `PLANS`.`store_attribute1`                                    
                               AND`store_attribute2` = `PLANS`.`store_attribute2` 
                               AND`store_attribute3` = `PLANS`.`store_attribute3`
                              )
  AND `REPORTS`.`item` = `PLANS`.`item`
```

... I actually have no idea if the above query will even work.

Comment: Thanks for the input as always, Cam.